# How do I access the previous record in a rails block

Tags: ruby

So basically I need to return the value of the previous Point.

e.g. I'm on the *third* point. I need the point.kilometric_position of the *second* point.

Part of my controller action is pasted here. Thanks in advance!

```
def calculate
  @points = Point.all

  # loop through all the points
  @points.each do |point|
    # calculate the current kilometric position
    if point.kilometric_position.nil?
      # kilometric_position = previous_kilometric_position + distance
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your question is too vague - it doesn't specify what `distance` is, why you only want points with `kilometric_position` equalling nil to have their position calculated, and what the `kilometric_position` of the first point should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@points.each_with_index do |point, i|
  previous_point = @points[i-1] unless i==0

  next unless previous_point
  distance = point.distance_to(previous_point)
  # do something with distance
end
```

Comment: minor suggestion 
```
    @points.each_with_index do |point, i|
      next if i == 0 
      previous_point = @points[i-1]
  
      distance = point.distance_to(previous_point)
      # do something with distance
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a more ruby friendly method, use inject like this:

```
@points.inject do |previous,current|
  previous  # first time through, this is the first value
  current   # first time through, this is the second value

  # do a bunch of stuff

  previous = current
end
```

Comment: it only works for the first iteration. On the second `previous` becomes an array

Answer (score 0):

Would this be alright, seems inefficient but it's all I can think of right now:

```
@previous_point = @points[@points.index(point)-1]
```

Comment: Note that `@points[0]` would trigger `@points[-1]` if its `kilometric_position` is `nil`, which is the last point in `@points`. If that's the desired functionality then this works, otherwise you need to safeguard against that condition.

Answer (score 0):

I might do

```
def calculate
  # Why were you using @points rather than points?
  points = Point.all

  current_kilometric_position = 0
  # loop through all the points
  points.each do |point|
    point.kilometric_position = current_kilometric_position
    current_kilometric_position += distance
  end
end
```

but your question is too vague - it doesn't specify what `distance` is, why you only want points with `kilometric_position` equalling nil to have their position calculated, and what the `kilometric_position` of the first `point` should be.

Comment: The first point will have km position 0, and the it will be cumulative. The second will have km position = the distance between the first point and the second, the third will have the distance between the first and the second + the distance between the second and the third and so on.